# Rate Limit s3 Upload using Java API

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am using the java aws sdk to transfer large files to s3.  Currently I am using the upload method of the [TransferManager](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) class to enable multi-part uploads.  I am looking for a way to throttle the rate at which these files are transferred to ensure I don't disrupt other services running on this CentOS server.  Is there something I am missing in the API, or some other way to achieve this?

Comment: Even i am struggling with the same problem using AWS SDK .net API. Could you please suggest any solution to achieve throttling while s3 upload?

Answer (score 0):

Without support in the API for this, one approach is to wrap the s3 command with [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle).